# How to find force-writable files in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I was wondering if there is a way to find some files that have been made writable by a user.
Usually Perforce is not able to clobber these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of approaches to this problem. Start by reviewing the overall techniques here: https://community.perforce.com/s/article/3481

Comment: The link in the answer is dead. [This](https://community.perforce.com/s/article/3481) is the new url.

Comment: Thanks! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using recent versions of perforce, the `p4 reconcile -n ...` command will descend directories from your current location looking for anything new or changed where the change is *not* under source control (I.e. you haven't used `p4 edit`).

The command above will show you how perforce would reconcile these changes and if you remove the `-n` it will then add those files to the default change list for edit, add or delete as indicated when you run the command with `-n`.